# How to flip dataframe with column names and values within column while keeping all static columns in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe that has 500 columns, 2 columns ('FieldTitle', 'Value') columns whose rows I want to 'flip' into columns and df looks like this:

```
id    FieldTitle    Value   UID   number  XID
1       fname        aaa     12    123    345
1       lname        bbb     12    123    345
2       fname        ccc     23    432    543
2       lname        ddd     23    432    543
```

How do I make the dataframe look like this?:

```
id     fname     lname     UID    number  XID
1       aaa       bbb       12     123    345
2       ccc       ddd       23     432    543
```

currently when I pivot, only the columns in 'FieldTitle' and 'Value' are remaining while all the static columns get dropped.

pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Id', columns='FieldTitle', values='Value', aggfunc='first').reset_index()

I have also tried the below, with no success:

```
pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Id', columns='FieldTitle', values=['Value'], aggfunc='first').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass list of columns names to parameter `index`:

```
pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['id','UID','number','XID'], 
                                columns='FieldTitle', 
                                values='Value', 
                                aggfunc='first').reset_index()
print (pivoted_df)
FieldTitle  id  UID  number  XID fname lname
0            1   12     123  345   aaa   bbb
1            2   23     432  543   ccc   ddd
```

If want dynamically add values to `index` parameter:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['FieldTitle','Value']).tolist()

pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=cols, 
                                columns='FieldTitle', 
                                values='Value', 
                                aggfunc='first').reset_index()
print (pivoted_df)
```

Comment: If I have a list of 500 columns how would I pass them into index?

Comment: @RustyShackleford - This columns have same values per `id` like in question ?

Comment: I am not following the question. Some IDs will have more `FieldTitles` while others have less, but most will have the same values in `FieldTitles`

Comment: got error `ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length`

Comment: @RustyShackleford - it means some missing values, need `pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df.fillna('missing'), index=cols, 
                                columns='FieldTitle', 
                                values='Value', 
                                aggfunc='first').reset_index().replace('missing', np.nan)`

Comment: still getting the same error. however I can tell the system is processing something `ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length`

Comment: @RustyShackleford - Cannot simulate error. Are data confidental?

Comment: @RustyShackleford - Use `cols = df.columns.difference(['FieldTitle','Value']).tolist()`

Comment: it is still processing, I will get back to you.

Comment: @RustyShackleford - Supeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeer ;) Good news ;)